# DRF init error when use several serializer in one view

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Error: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

code:

```
class MyListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.role == "role1":
            return Serializer1
        elif self.role == "role2":
            return Serializer2
        return Serializer3

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        result = super().get_serializer_context()
        if self.role == "role2":
            result['my_context'] = something
        return result



class Serializer2(ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def __init__(self, instance, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(instance, **kwargs)
        self.unit_id_list = self.context.get('my_context')
```

**init** is customized only for "Serializer2".
An error occurs only when self.role is "role2".
If I delete the **init** code of "Serializer2", it works normally.
What could be the cause? The error point is as follows.

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/38a74b42da10576857d6bf8bd82a73b15d12a7ed/rest_framework/generics.py#L114

Totally not understand

Comment: def __init__(self, instance=None, **kwargs):

OMG When i add "instance=None" it works!